# Python regex - Optional fields in a string

Tags: python, regex, parsing, output, pager

I'm trying to teach myself python and I'm quite new to parsing concepts.  I'm trying to parse the output from my fire service pager, it seems to follow a consistent pattern as follows:

```
(UNIT1, UNIT2, UNIT3) 911-STRU (Box# 12345) aBusiness 12345 Street aTown (Xstr CrossStreet1/CrossStreet2) building fire, persons reported #F123456
```

It seems that each section is separated by the use of () brackets the fields break down as follows

```
(Responded trucks) CallSource-JobClassification (Box number if available) Building Name, Building Address (Cross streets) Description of job #JobNumber
```

Scrap that, just got a call while writing this.  If no box number is provided then that section is skipped entirely meaning that it goes straight to the address section, therefore I can't count on parsing using the brackets.

So to the parsing experts out there, can I attack this with pyparsing or will I need a custom parser?  Furthermore can I target specific sections with a parser so it doesn't matter what order they appear in, as is the case with the Box# being an optional field?

My goal is to take this input, tidy it up with parsing and then send it via Twitter, SMS, email or all of the above.

Many thanks in advance

EDIT:

I've got this 99% working using the following code

```
import re

sInput = ('(UNIT123, UNIT1234) AMB-MED APPLE HEADQUARTERS 1 INFINITE LOOP CUPERTINO. (XStr DE ANZA BLVD/MARIANI AVE) .42YOM CARDIAC ARREST. #F9876543')

#sInput = '(UNIT123, UNIT1234) ALARM-SPRNKLR (Alarm Type MANUAL/SMOKE) (Box 12345) APPLE HEADQUARTERS 1 INFINITE LOOP CUPERTINO. (XStr DE ANZA BLVD/MARIANI AVE) #F9876544'

# Matches truck names using the consistent four uppercase letters followed by three - four numbers.
pAppliances = re.findall(r'\w[A-Z]{3}\d[0-9]{2,3}', sInput)

# Matches source and job type using the - as a guide, this section is always proceeded by the trucks on the job
# therefore is always proceeded by a ) and a space. Allows between 3-9 characters either side of the - this is
# to allow such variations as 911-RESC, FAA-AIRCRAFT etc.
pJobSource = re.findall(r'\) ([A-Za-z1-9]{2,8}-[A-Za-z1-9]{2,8})', sInput)

# Gets address by starting at (but ignoring) the job source e.g. -RESC and capturing everything until the next . period
# the end of the address section always has a period. Uses ?; to ignore up to two sets of brackets that may appear in
# the string for things such as box numbers or alarm types.

pAddress = re.findall(r'-[A-Z1-9]{2,8} (.*?)\. \(', sInput)
pAddressOptionTwo = re.findall(r'-[A-Z1-9]{2,8}(?: \(.*?\))(?: \(.*?\)) (.*?)\. \(', sInput)

# Finds the specified cross streets as they are always within () brackets, each bracket has a space immediately
# before or after and the work XStr is always present.
pCrossStreet = re.findall(r' \((XStr.*?)\) ', sInput)

# The job details / description is always contained between two . periods e.g.  .42YOM CARDIAC ARREST.  each period
# has a space either immediately before or after.
pJobDetails = re.findall(r' \.(.*?)\. ', sInput)

# Job number is always in the format #F followed by seven digits.  The # is always proceeded by a space.  Allowed
# between 1 and 8 digits for future proofing.
pJobNumber = re.findall(r' (#F\d{0,7})', sInput)

print pAppliances
print pJobSource
print pAddress
print pCrossStreet
print pJobDetails
print pJobNumber
```

When run on the uncommented sInput string it returns the following

```
['UNIT123', 'UNIT1234']
['AMB-MED']
['APPLE HEADQUARTERS 1 INFINITE LOOP CUPERTINO']
['XStr DE ANZA BLVD/MARIANI AVE']
['42YOM CARDIAC ARREST']
['#F9876543']
```

However when I run it on the commented sInput string I get the following

```
['UNIT123', 'UNIT1234']
['ALARM-SPRNKLR']
['(Alarm Type MANUAL/SMOKE) (Box 12345) APPLE HEADQUARTERS 1 INFINITE LOOP CUPERTINO']
['XStr DE ANZA BLVD/MARIANI AVE']
[]
['#F9876544']
```

This is because two option bracket sets have been included in this message. I managed to correct this using the pAddressOptionTwo line however when the first string is then applied it returns no address at all as it didn't find the brackets.

So the new refocused question is:

How can I make an optional argument in the regex line.  If there are brackets present ignore them and their contents and return the rest of the string OR if there are no brackets present continue as per normal.

Comment: So if there is no box number/cross street, the parentheses would be gone, too? In other words, the record might look like `(UNIT1) 911-STRU aBusiness 12345 Street aTown building fire, persons reported #F123456`, in which case the followup question is: How can you determine where one part of the message ends and the next one begins?

Comment: Yes Tim that it exactly the problem. I've had some limited success using regular expressions. I can get it to work perfectly with one message but when you add a new message with a slightly different format half of it falls apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best/easiest option is to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), defining a pattern that will match all or parts of your input string and extract the pieces that you're interested in.

[PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) will probably work fine too. I have not used it myself but the first few examples looks like some kind of higher level wrapper around regex, although I would expect it differs in many aspects once you delve deeper into it.

Another option is to define a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and create a parser from it using [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/). That would probably be overkill for your use case however, as it is aimed more at parsing programming language and natural language syntax.

Comment: Simon I may love and hate you for many years for introducing me to regular expressions. I've just had my mind blown. There are so many possibilities for it's use. I have run into issues however with the message format varying slightly. I'll have to tinker some more.

Comment: Haha, I'm happy to hear that! I'm sure then you'll be amused by the iconic quote [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/223634). :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know pyparsing, then it might be easier to go with it.  The `()` can always be treated as optional. Pyparsing will make certain things easier out of the box.

If you are not so familiar with pyparsing, and your main goal is learning python, then hand craft your own parser in pure python.  Nothing better at learning a new language than re-inventing some wheels :-)